# Replaces all values with "NA" in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na, data-cleaning

I have a set of data

```
x <- seq(1, 10, by=1)
y <- seq(1, 10, by=1)
data <- expand.grid(x,y)
```

I would like to create a new set of data called NA_data and replaces all the 100 values in that data frame with "NA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply with `NA` as any operation with `NA` results in `NA` and here we could either multiply or add (`+`) or subtract (`-`) or divide (`/`) and it still returns `NA`

```
NA_data <- data * NA
```

---

Or another option is

```
NA_data <- data[rep(nrow(data) + 1, nrow(data)),]
```

---

Or use the `matrix` way

```
NA_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(data), 
        ncol = ncol(data), dimnames = list(NULL, names(data)))
```